# binding a dropdownlist to a list<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get an empty dropdown when I do this.  I have a dropdownlist that I am attempting to bind a simple List to a dropdownlist, but its empty after binding.

```
        List<string> divlist = omgr.GetPackingList();
        ddlDivision.DataSource = divlist;
        ddlCoordinators.DataBind();
```

Im being lazy and not creating a poco class and using the DataTextField/DataValueField, but it seems this has worked in the past.  What am I missing?

[edited]
Duh...the items cant be single-value

Comment: Are you really binding a different ddl, or is it just a typo?

Comment: Ha ha, I didn't see that at first either!